# I can't send email

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

I have an app which sends out an email at a time selected by the Timepicker. Everything works fine except for the email part.

*Here is my code for the email class :*

```
package com.example.myapplication;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.activation.CommandMap;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

import static com.example.myapplication.Pop_up.item;
import static com.example.myapplication.Pop_up.rad;
import static com.example.myapplication.Pop_up.rad1;
import static com.example.myapplication.Pop_up.rb1;
import static com.example.myapplication.Pop_up.s1;
import static com.example.myapplication.Pop_up.s3;
import static com.example.myapplication.Pop_up_2.message;


public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
private String _user;
private String _pass;

private String[] _to;
private String _from;

private String _port;
private String _sport;

private String _host;

private String _subject;
private String _body;

private boolean _auth;

private boolean _debuggable;

private Multipart _multipart;


public GMailSender() {
    if (rb1 != null && rad.isChecked()){
        message=s1;
    }else if(rb1 != null && rad1.isChecked())
    {
        message=item;
    }
    _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server
    _port = "465"; // default smtp port
    _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port

    _user = "user.name@gmail.com"; // username
    _pass = "userpass"; // password
    _from = "user.name@gmail.com"; // email sent from
    _subject = s3; // email subject
    _body = message; // email body

    _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
}

public GMailSender(String user, String pass) {
    this();

    _user = user;
    _pass = pass;
}

public boolean send() throws Exception {
    Properties props = _setProperties();

    if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) {
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);

        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));

        InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) {
            addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]);
        }
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

        msg.setSubject(_subject);
       // msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        // setup message body
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // Put parts in message
        msg.setContent(_multipart);

        // send email
        Transport.send(msg);

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
}

@Override
public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass);
}

private Properties _setProperties() {
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host);

    if(_debuggable) {
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    }

    if(_auth) {
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    }

    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    return props;
}

// the getters and setters
public String getBody() {
    return _body;
}

public void setBody(String _body) {
    this._body = _body;
}

public void setTo(String[] toArr) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this._to=toArr;
}

public void setFrom(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this._from=string;
}

public void setSubject(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this._subject=string;
}

// more of the getters and setters …..
}
```

*Here is my code for sending the email:*

```
 GMailSender m = new GMailSender("user.name@gmail.com", "userpass");

    String[] toArr = {s4,"name@gmail.oom"};
    m.setTo(toArr);
    m.setFrom("user.name@gmail.com");
    m.setSubject(s3);
    m.setBody(message);
    try {
        m.addAttachment(path);

        if(m.send()) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Email was sent successfully :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Email was not sent :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        //Toast.makeText(context, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e);
    }
```

But for some reason I keep getting the toast *"Email was not sent :("* . Where am I going wrong? Please help.

Comment: what was the exception ?can you share that too?

Comment: @soorapadman nobody said there is an Exception thrown. his send method returns false, it doesn't throw an Exception.

Comment: @Abhishek you'll need to debug your send method.

Comment: @Stultuske oops i didnt read it properly.I thought it prints exception part

Comment: @Stultuske it shows `/storage/emulated/0/IMG-20190324-WA0000.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`. That's strange cause I have that file in my external storage with that exact same name.

Comment: I have the file on my SD card

Comment: yes, but I doubt your code is looking on an external storage unit

Comment: So does that mean that `Environment.getExternalDirectory()` checks into my internal memory? How do I chang that?

Comment: What is the value of `s3`

Comment: @Vinay Avasthi S3 is the subject body of the email which is declared in another activity and imported from there by the new activity

Comment: One of the values in `if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals(""))` is null. Log the values of each of these before `if` statement and you will know which one is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the jpg file to my internal memory solved the problem.